# How can i fix the npm start error problem in react?

Tags: reactjs, npm-start

After installing react, I'm trying to use the command:

```
npm start
```

to run react app but it gives me this error.
[image: Error details]

> code NOENT

Comment: The error seems pretty clear, you do not have a `package.json` file in the folder from which you are running your npm command. Make sure you are in the correct folder or perhaps create a new package.json for your project e.g. `npm init`. The space in the folder name might also be an issue, try renaming it to something without a space e.g. `learn-react` or something like that.

Comment: Remove the space from the folder name (React lear -> React-lear)

Comment: Package json is inside my-app folder, while your cli is inside React-lear folder if I see correctly. Do `cd my-app` and `npm start` and hopefuly it will work.

Answer (score 0):

go to the `my-app` directory and run the command `npm start`

Answer (score 0):

You are not in the correct directory. At the moment of execution you are in `React LEAR` but you `package.json` is inside `my-app`. Go inside `my-app` and then execute `npm start`

Answer (score -1):

delete node_modules and package-lock.json file.

then run,

```
npm i legacy-peer-deps or npm i --force
```

hope this will fix your error, try to share package.json file for such errors

Comment: How can i run or use npm start and see output in localhost/